# Styling elements with a dot (.) in the class name

Tags: css, class

Hay I have an element like this

```
<span class='a.b'>
```

Unfortunately this class name comes from an eCommerce application and cannot be changed.

Can I style a class name with a dot in it?

like

```
.a.b { }
```

Comment: What insane system will generate such a classname?

Comment: Partial dupe, but probably answers the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Comment: insane system: class names are keys from properties file. Different properties files for different languages allow for dynamic formatting based on the language-independent but semantically same content.

Comment: "What insane system will generate such a classname?" 
Shopify does..ugh.

Comment: @SLaks - google, facebook..youtube..gmail..basically any large web system

Comment: "What insane system will generate such a classname?"  so does angular's ui-router

Comment: Modern example: utility classes like `p-1.5`, `m-0.5`, and so on in Tailwind (for specifying dimensions of padding, margins, etc.).

Answer (score 136, accepted):

```
.a\.b { }
```

However there could be browsers around that don't support this.

Comment: like? Would firefox 1.5 +, Safari 3+ and IE 6+ support it?

Comment: I'm not sure (thus the "could"). However IE6 surprisingly does.

Comment: It was IE5.x, and early versions of Opera, that didn't support this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. Say i want to style span.a.b (a 'span' with the class of '.a.b'), how would i do that?

Comment: You need to escape the dot that is part of the class name with a backslash, thus in this case: `span.a\.b`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Mrafq/1/

Comment: For a class name of `.a.b` you would actually need `span.\.a\.b`.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Yes, but the class name in question is `a.b` not `.a.b`.

Comment: @RoToRa - I was addressing dotty's latest comment: "a 'span' with the class of `.a.b`". This is where meaningless names like `a` and `b` make examples unclear.

Comment: In Google Chrome I get it to work with double backslashes... => .a\\.b {}

Comment: ID name with dot also need this way to escape.

Comment: @algorhythm guess you can use both selectors, eg, `.a\.b, .a\\.b { }`

Comment: Today all major browsers support it (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari).

Answer (score 51):

Coming very late to this party, but you can use attribute selectors.

In your case, to target the `class='a.b'` element, you could use:

```
[class~="a.b"] {...}
// or
span[class~="a.b"] {...}
```

---

Additionally, here is the full list of attribute selectors.

**Attribute Present Selector**

```
// Selects an element if the given attribute is present

// HTML
<a target="_blank">...</a>

// CSS
a[target] {...}
```

**Attribute Equals Selector**

```
// Selects an element if the given attribute value
// exactly matches the value stated

// HTML
<a href="http://google.com/">...</a>

// CSS
a[href="http://google.com/"] {...}
```

**Attribute Contains Selector**

```
// Selects an element if the given attribute value
// contains at least once instance of the value stated

// HTML
<a href="/login.php">...</a>

// CSS
a[href*="login"] {...}
```

**Attribute Begins With Selector**

```
// Selects an element if the given attribute value
// begins with the value stated

// HTML
<a href="https://chase.com/">...</a>

// CSS
a[href^="https://"] {...}
```

**Attribute Ends With Selector**

```
// Selects an element if the given attribute value
// ends with the value stated

// HTML
<a href="/docs/menu.pdf">...</a>

// CSS
a[href$=".pdf"] {...}
```

**Attribute Spaced Selector**

```
// Selects an element if the given attribute value
// is whitespace-separated with one word being exactly as stated

// HTML
<a href="#" rel="tag nofollow">...</a>

// CSS
a[rel~="tag"] {...}
```

**Attribute Hyphenated Selector**

```
// Selects an element if the given attribute value is
// hyphen-separated and begins with the word stated

// HTML
<a href="#" lang="en-US">...</a>

// CSS
a[lang|="en"] {...}
```

[Source: learn.shayhowe.com](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/complex-selectors/#attribute-selectors)

Comment: The attribute spaced selector is probably more appropriate for the general case, as there may be other classed on the element that you don't want to select by.

Comment: What would a compound be like?   img[data~="120"].recognition_template  Where the data="120" and class ="recognition_template"?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could scan the elements for these classes and add a class that you could style.

For instance, scan all elements with the “a.b” class and then add a new “style-ab” class or some such.

I haven’t posted any example code for this as people may want to use vanilla Javascript or jQuery and it’s a simple enough thing to do.

To clarify, my gaming framework does exactly as the OP described so translations could be applied to certain divs and spans. It’s not  a nasty way to decide class names, it’s just useful for people creating markup when using a dictionary that has keys for phrases

Comment: Please add vanilla JS for those of us that need a starting point. Otherwise your answer is limited to those who understand how to 'scan all elements'

Answer (score -9):

Yes you can.
The meaning of CSS class name like '.a.b' is targeting elements that have CSS name with 'a' which also has class name 'b',that's to say you have both of these class in the same element. Just as  div.cssname targeting div elements with cssname.

Comment: This has been down voted because you haven't understood the question. The OP doesn't have any elements with class "a" or class "b", he is trying to style an element with the class "a.b".