# html/css what do elements with multiple dots mean

Tags: html, css

If I want multiple css classes applied, I use `<div class = "c1 c2 c2">`
I am looking at some code. 
What does `<div class = "c1.c2.c3">` mean?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447329/styling-elements-with-a-dot-in-the-class-name

Comment: The spaces mean that the div has all specific classes. The dot notation never saw before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you have is correct, however you don't need the dots in your second `<div>` element (`<div class='c1.c2.c3'></div>`). (*Unless you actually have an element that is explicitly named c1.c2.c3, which might cause some issues with CSS style declarations, unless you escape the leading slashes*)

The dots are referring to CSS style rules, indicating an element has multiple classes, or in this case, classes c1, c2 and c3.

```
.c1.c2.c3
{
    //Styles an element that has classes c1, c2 and c3
} 

.c1.c2
{
    //Styles an element that has classes c1 and c2
}
```

whereas with spacing, it refines the scope:

```
.c1 .c2 .c3
{
    //Styles an element that has class c3 within an element c2, 
    //within an element c1.
}
```

**[Example of both cases](http://jsfiddle.net/uxyef/)**

Comment: Thanks, so if it only has c1 and c2, they would not be applied?  i.e. how is it different from spaces.

Answer (score 1):

`<div class = "c1.c2.c3">` means exactly what it looks like:  the class name of this div element is `c1.c2.c3`.  The CSS selector for it would look like this:

```
.c1\.c2\.c3 {
    // styles here
}
```

This is very different from the CSS selector for `<div class="c1 c2 c3">`, which looks like this:

```
.c1.c2.c3 {
    // styles here
}
```