# What kind of CSS class is the below?

Tags: css

This may be a very silly question to others but I just came across something like this

```
<div class = "inventory.InStock"></div>
```

I don't know how much about CSS and tried to search in Google by Nested CSS / Modular CSS but may be I am in the wrong direction.

What it is and how to use it?

[image]

Comment: It would help to know where you saw this.

Comment: sure, i am updating that.

Comment: That's an invalid class name (they can't contain the full-stop/period character `.`). More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: That looks like shopify syntax or some other javascript framework.

Comment: I got this while watching the video of Udi dahan SOA building Part-2

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447329/styling-elements-with-a-dot-in-the-class-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a CSS class name with a `.` character. You can style it by escaping the character in your CSS file:

```
inventory\.InStock {

  /* your styles here */

}
```

Or by using attribute selectors:

```
div[class="inventory.InStock"] {

  /* your styles here */

}
```

However, there will definitely be browsers that do not support this.

Comment: Or by attribute selectors: `[class="inventory.InStock"]`