# How to set property of style sheet using d3 js?

Tags: d3.js

How to set `opacity:1` for **"labelwebmetro.com"** class using **d3 js**.

```
<g class="circle" transform="translate(686.7254745357253,1011.2761564139669)">
<text x="12" dy=".35em" class="labelwebmetro.com" style="opacity: 0;">webmetro.com</text>
<circle style="fill: rgb(255, 127, 14);" r="40" class="circlewebmetro.com"/>
</g>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [selection.style](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#style) on selector as,

```
d3.select("g text.myClass").style("opacity", 1);
```

The thing is class name `labelwebmetro.com` may not work because it contains a dot(.) however you can give it a try. If you can replace it somehow with something more clean it would be good. Besides class name with dot(.) is not cross browser supported i believe.

Check this out [**how to use a CSS class with a dot**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447329/styling-elements-with-a-dot-in-the-class-name).

Answer (score 0):

d3.select selects first element with given criteria. In this case, we are looking for text with class specific class.
Then style function modifies style of the selection.

```
d3.select('text.labelwebmetro.com').style('opacity', 1.0);
```

If you want to change every element with class `labelwebmetro.com`, then you could do

```
d3.selectAll('.labelwebmetro.com').style('opacity', 1.0);
```