# Add View Name to CSS Class on Body

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking for a way to echo out the view name and place it in to the master template inside the body tag as a CSS Class.

The reason for this is I have some pages where certain CSS Elements need to change however inline code is inefficient and I don't really want to make a dedicated view for that one page.

So, for example, if I was to land on the home page the body tag would be:

```
<body class="home">
```

Where if I was to go to about the about us page, it would change to:

```
<body class="about">
```

Comment: if you are using dynamic urls like ?action=home or ?action=about then you can use <body class="<?php $_GET['action'] ?>"?

Comment: @Matt Hi Matt, I'm using Laravel so I'm assuming that I'd need to make a controller for capturing the view name then convert it to a variable. Once it's in a variable, I'd need to echo it to the class like {{ $viewname }} or something along these lines. It's just getting to this point that I'm confused about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add to filters (or routes):

```
View::composer('*', function($view){
    View::share('view_name', $view->getName());
});
```

You can then access the view name using `$view_name`

Comment: Yeah it's spot on! So easy to knock out applications once you get used to the system. The blade template system just makes it too easy haha!

Comment: Indeed, it's a pleasure to use, and like you say - one can knock up a lovely looking and functional PoC / prototype in no time.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<body class="@yield('class')">
```

And on your views

```
@section('class', 'Your boddy class')
```

Comment: Where should the second code be put ? I tried before @extends('layouts.app') and after, but doesnt do anything, my body class stays empty :/

Comment: Nice answer!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Use this in your controller

```
View::composer('*', function($view){

    View::share('view_name', $view->getName());

});
```

Use this in your view page

```
<body class="{{$view_name}}">
```

Answer (score 5):

Open your `AppServiceProvider` class, `boot()` method and insert this code:

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    $view_name = str_replace('.', ' ', $view->getName());
    View::share('view_name', $view_name);
});
```

Then you can access `$view_name` variable in your view.

Regarding @Stuart answer, use `$view->getName()` will returns exactly view path with dot notation. For example, you view is under `resources/views/settings/index` directory, your view name is: `settings.index`.

So then? the class name will contains `dot` character means that is little more confusing whilst writing CSS. See this thread:
[Styling elements with a dot (.) in the class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447329/styling-elements-with-a-dot-in-the-class-name)

By replacing `.` with space, the class name in above example will becomes `settings index` and you can use `.settings` selector, or `.index` selector, or `.setting.index` selector.

#### Custom Class Name

The above method is for automatically generate class name, you have many methods:

**`@yield()` and `@section()`**

```
<body class="@yield('body-class')">
```

Then in your views:

```
@section('body-class', 'your-class-name')
```

**`@stack()` and `@push()`**

Since Laravel 5.4, you can use `@stack` and `@push`, this allows you push as many time as you want.

```
<body class="@stack('body-class')">
```

Then in your views

```
@push('body-class', 'your-class-name')
@push('body-class', ' another-class-name')
```

Comment: IMHO more flexible with stack/push method

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set in your controller (in contructor or in action's method) class name with:

`View::share('bodyClass', 'nameOfCertainClass');`

and then:

`<body class="{{$bodyClass or 'default}}'">`