# How to retrieve the view name in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5, view

I've tried a variety of ways, including the popular post here: [Add View Name to CSS Class on Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922644/add-view-name-to-css-class-on-body)

But it pulls up the master template, rather than the sub-template name. I use @yield and @extends and such. So at the moment this is what a part of my file system looks like in my views:

```
-Views
--Layouts
---=master.blade.php
--Shipments
---=index.blade.php
```

So my shipments.index file will @extends('layouts.master'), just so I don't have so much redundancy. However, referencing the above post, I get the following result:

`<div id="page" class="layouts.master">`

which is not what I'd like, I'd prefer at the very least "shipments.index", I don't mind if it's longer, I just want it identified.

Comment: Look into something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46839273/3226121). It's used to get the view directory, but with a bit of modification it could work for you

Comment: @ljubadr - what would I change in it? Using it outright just gives me a blank response in the html. No errors or anything, just nothing responding using the {{ $view_folder }} - do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I've created an answer, take a look and let me know if it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 get view name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458845/laravel-5-get-view-name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Laravel [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers)

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a
>   view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view
>   each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize
>   that logic into a single location.

In the file `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`, edit the `public function boot()` method

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot(Application $app)
{
    view()->composer('*', function($view) {
        view()->share('view_name', $view->getName());
    });
}
```

After this, in any blade template you will now have access to a variable

`{{ $view_name }}`

Comment: It looks like this is [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36022521/3226121). Just saw other question

Comment: This version worked! Thank you so very much for the help!!

Comment: One quick note: This will work for the view that you are loading, but it will not work for sub views, as it will always show main view name (when you do the `@include('another.view')`)

Comment: @Matthew I'm glad that I could help