# scss providing css classes with . inside

Tags: for-loop, variables, sass

I have a for loop in scss and I would like to output something like this:

```
.font-1.0em {font-size:1.0em} 
.font-1.1em {font-size:1.1em} 
.font-1.2em {font-size:1.2em} ....
```

I wrote the scss as this

```
@for $i from 1 through 50 {
    $val: $i + em;

    $val2: $i / 10 + em;

    &.font-#{$val} {
        font-size: #{$val2} ;
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
.font-10em {font-size:1.0em} 
.font-11em {font-size:1.1em} 
.font-12em {font-size:1.2em} ....
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: What is it you aren't happy with, is it that the numbers in the class name are not decimals? Also, dots in class names is unconventional and would require escaping the character in the css - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3447336/3909886)

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to achive should be fairly easily solved, by using, same formula you have in `$val2` in your `$val`

```
@for $i from 1 through 50 {
    $val: $i / 10 + em;

    $val2: $i / 10 + em;

    &.font-#{$val} {
        font-size: #{$val2} ;
    }
}
```

compiles to

```
.font-0.1em {
    font-size: 0.1em;
}

.font-0.2em {
    font-size: 0.2em;
}
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't work with all sass implementations, I get an error if I try to compile this with dart-sass but not with libsass.

Comment: I compiled it with scss just fine, might be problem of compilation rather than implementation.

Comment: I belive you, in that case your parser doesnt allow it, so either get different one, or change the way you digest the end data, the parser you linked doesnt like dot in variable, so there isnt much space for fixing it.